# Unable to send email to all recipient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, smtpclient

**Description:**

I deployed our MVC application in Azure, in 2 different environment i.e. UAT and Production. And that MVC application have a functionality of sending email. While sending an email from UAT is got sent successfully but while sending from Production is throwing an exception i.e. Unable to send email to all recipient.
Code and configuration for both environment are same.

Comment: which exception you are getting?

Comment: Unable to send email to all recipient.

Comment: Are you sending emails using Sendgrid from Azure?

Comment: No, I'm simply using C# code

Comment: Due to some security reason some of time gmail does not allow to login from external virtual machine like from azure cloud so I will recommend you you should do this with Sendgrid it is also free. And for more information follow this links http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150975/2798643 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26886766/2798643

Answer (score 1):

Try to send your email using of **sendgrid** on Azure. Azure support for it.
Follow below article it will be helpful.

[How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)